# heroku: How to swich apps from another environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I deployed my rails app to heroku.
After that, I have created new rails app on the another environment(cloud9).

I'd like to switch old app to new one.

How can I set up `git` and `heroku` on the new cloud9 environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, since you alrady have a completly new project why don't just create a new heroku app and push your code to that new app ?

As for how you could do it, Heroku works with git so you would have to push the entire code of your new project to the same repository and then use the heroku command to push your code from git to heroku which will overwrite everything.

You could also open the hidden git folder of your new app and paste the heroku repository to the new project. In your git config file, heroku defines a heroku repo to which git can push your code:

```
[remote "heroku"]
    url = https://git.heroku.com/heroku-app-name1234.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
```

If you go to your old project, copy those lines and paste them in your new project. When you run the heroku command:

```
git push heroku master
```

It will push your new project to the old Heroku repo which will again, overwrite everything with your new code.

**UPDATE**

If you have an existing Heroku app, Heroku will create a git repo as I said and you can add that repo as a remote to any new project:

```
git remote -v    // returns your remote heroku git repos of your existing project
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/your-app-1624.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/your-app-1624.git (push)

heroku git:remote -a your-app-1624  // adds the existing heroku repo to any project you want
```

**UPDATE 2**

Then you have to push to heroku by overwriting the existing project using the -f option.

```
git push -f heroku master
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Alexander Luna.
Although I open the gitconfig (`git config --global --edit`), there is no `[remote "heroku"]` line.
How can I find this file?

Comment: I use Atom (editor) and I can open all the git files directly there if you don't use Atom, check my updated answer

Comment: Thank you for updating, @Alexander Luna. The following message was displayed when I tried to `git push heroku master` after `heroku git:remote -a your-app-1624`. The message is `error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/xxx.git' Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again. See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.`Should I post as another question?

Comment: Ok, sorry I forgot to mention that you have to overwrite the push request to Heroku with the -f options like this: git push -f heroku master. I update my answer.

Comment: This is a belated note to thank you for your update, @ Alexander Luna. It works!

Comment: @SamuraiBlue I'm glad it does.